# How to display the single-product page in full width woocommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

a link for the single product page:

http://umsi.me/uniikmedia/?product=versailles-courtyard

I wanted to know if there is a way to sterch the product summary drop down menus all the way to the right without affecting the mobile site?

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you wanted

```
#content-shop{width:100%}
```

This css will move the product dorpdown all the way to right side

Comment: yes it did the trick the content moved to the right. is there anyway to strech it to the left just to have smaller white gap between them?
thanks.

Comment: yes use this code '.single-product div.images {
width: 59.793103448276%;
}.single-product div.summary {
width: 29.67816091954%;
margin-right: 8%;
}'